# How to keep a process running throughout pod lifecycle?

Tags: kubernetes

As per [this link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/#understanding-init-containers), all init containers always run to completion. And init container must complete successfully before the next one starts.

In my case, there is a case where i want to keep a process running throughout pod lifecycle, quite similar to the way [emptyDir](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir) are preserved throughout pod lifecycle.

I did all my research but couldn't find a way. Are there are workaround to achieve the goal?

Comment: If I really had to do this, I'd use a second (main) container, or a process manager like supervisord inside the primary container; what's your higher-level goal?

Comment: My high level goal is very simple. Keep a process alive even after init containers are completed. Can you share your example with supervisord if possible?

Comment: What's the process?  Why can't you run it in a separate pod managed by a separate deployment?

Answer (score 1):

Use of `shareProcessNamespace: true` helps in such case. We just need to start a child process in background via init container.

Here is an example

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    app: demo
  name: demo
spec:
  shareProcessNamespace: true
  initContainers:
    - name: iapp
      image: nicolaka/netshoot:latest
      command:
        - "bash"
      args:
        - "-c"
        - "tail -f /dev/null & echo iapp"
  containers:
    - name: app
      image: nicolaka/netshoot:latest
      command:
        - "sleep"
      args:
        - "inifinity"
```

After pod is running, when we exec into `app` container, and do `ps aux`. We can see `tail -f /dev/null` still there. Which confirms that we can have a process running throughout pod lifecycle.